Beamer fade in/out image
I have a bunch of images which I want to make appear on a slide without having to click to transition. Each image should fade in to 100% opacity with a controllable delay (not too long), followed by the next image, and so on -- but this should not require a mouse click or key press.
Something like How can I fade out image?, except that I'd like to be able to go back to the previous slide and I would prefer not to keep clicking or pressing a key for the fade in/transition effect: it should get initiated by loading the slide.
Is there a way to do this? I don't have an MWE aside from the example in the post above.

I fixed the question.
Suppose my slide is #2
I use the code in the post linked above or page 135 of the Beamer manual (https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). However, I change the commands to \animate<2-2> and \animate<1-3>{\opaqueness}{0}{100}.
However, what I really want is for the sequence to play without a mouse click -- in full-screen mode on a compatible PDF reader.

Well, in Okular, I always have to click to start a presentation after switching to full screen. It doesn't even display the presentation until I do that - it's just a standard Okular thing. So if your PDF reader does that, there's nothing Beamer can do. But once you've started the presentation, of course, you can control what happens. So it should work in Adobe, for example, without a click, provided you start on the first slide.

To trigger the animation as soon as the frame is shown, just change the slide number on which the animation begins to 1.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcount\opaqueness
\begin{frame}<1-101>
  \animate<1-100>
  \animatevalue<1-100>{\opaqueness}{0}{100}
  \begin{colormixin}{\the\opaqueness!averagebackgroundcolor}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [opacity=\opaqueness/100, scale=0.3] {\includegraphics{tiger}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      Tiger
    \end{center}
  \end{colormixin}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

You cannot configure this so that going back returns to the previous frame. At least, I can't think of how that might be done. What you could do is make a link back to the previous slide, which you could click on to return in a single jump. For example,
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  No tiger here.\label{frame:no-tiger}
\end{frame}
\newcount\opaqueness
\begin{frame}<1-101>
  \animate<1-100>
  \animatevalue<1-100>{\opaqueness}{0}{100}
  \begin{colormixin}{\the\opaqueness!averagebackgroundcolor}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [opacity=\opaqueness/100, scale=0.3] {\includegraphics{tiger}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      Tiger \ref{frame:no-tiger}
    \end{center}
  \end{colormixin}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

That's incompatible with starting the animation immediately, though, since re-displaying the first slide will restart the animation, too, if the first slide initiates the animation. So I'm not clear how you envisage combining the two ....
Regrettably Okular-on-X can't manage to produce usable images right now - never mind animations. Hence the lack of visual aids in an answer about visual aids.

Thank you! So the problem with the first solution is that once the animation completely loads up, one goes to the next slide automatically (imagine having a \begin{frame} ... \end{frame} after the last \end{frame} in your code). How do you stop that from happening?
So let's say this is a 3 frame sequence:  [click]  [click]  ...and so on.

@leastaction You control which slides are animated and what is on which slide. But are you talking about frames or slides? The second example uses 2 frames. The first frame has 1 slide. The second frame has ... lots. When I use this I typically then have more stuff on another slide of the same frame. But you might also be talking about the next frame.

Consider a 3-frame document where the first frame is the Intro slide, the second frame contains the animation, and the third frame is again a static slide. When I add a 3rd frame to your code, the animation does play immediately as desired but then it advances to the next frame. I don't want that to happen.

@leastaction You can just add another slide. I'll edit one in.

I was able to add a frame and update the count, but the issue is still that one cannot go back to the frame before the animation frame, even with a link.
I have since decided to just have the images show up on click. But thank you for your help -- this was fun to experiment with. I am accepting your answer.

@leastaction The link should definitely work as that is absolutely standard. There is simply no way Beamer would work at all without hyperlink functionality and \label/\refs are automatically made into hypertargets/links. However, the link will not work on first compilation. It may even take three or four runs for things to settle down, though two should theoretically be another, I believe. Which engine are you using and are you certain your editor is not configured to delete auxillary files between compilations?

No, that's not the sort of problem I have. The link exists but it is unusable for going back to frame 1 once the animation ends.

@leastaction It works fine for me. I just tested the code I posted above, copying back from here just in case. And clicking on the 1 in Tiger 1 takes me back to the first frame. If I click onto the next slide, the animation plays again and I can click on 1 again and .... I compiled 3 times with pdfTeX, though I don't suppose 3 was necessary. I also tried with another frame after, clicking forwards to that and then clicking the link etc. It all worked fine. You didn't say which engine or I'd have tested with that one.

Thank you @cfr! I just checked it again, and indeed it does work. I added a third frame and was able to go back to the end of the animation too. I used pdfTeX in Texshop (and VS Code).

An animate-based solution for easy navigation between the slides using ⇑ and ⇓ on the keyboard. The animation is embedded in a single slide. Works in Okular and Acrobat Reader:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  No tiger here.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   \begin{center}
     \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{25}
       \multiframe{101}{rOpacity=0+0.01}{
         \tikz \node [opacity=\rOpacity, scale=0.3] {\includegraphics{tiger}};
       }
     \end{animateinline}
   \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \textsc{\Huge The End.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

